# Which data type occupy the least space in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, out-of-memory

I'm fairly new to Python, and I want to optimizes my code because I am getting `Runtime Error NZEC with error code 137`. For example, I need to find the number of numbers that is divisible by 2 by list comprehension (this is just an example)

```
print(len(['' for i in range(n) if i%2==0]))
```

So, can I replace '' with something that takes up the least space (specifically, in Python 3.8.1)?
Currently, I am using an blank tuple.

Comment: Don't build a list at all if you just want to count things. Even if your real code can't be simplified to `(n+1)//2`, if you're just counting, don't build a list.

Comment: Yes, but my code needs list comprehension to iterate over another list.

Comment: No you don't. There are plenty of ways to iterate over a list without using a list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're just counting the length of a generator's output: instead of converting the generator to a list, which will need to allocate the entirety in memory, just do a running sum:

```py
print(sum(1 for i in range(n) if i%2==0))
```

It takes essentially no memory running this with n=10**8, whereas `len([...])` takes ~2GB on my machine.

Comment: Wait, so sum takes less memory than len then, does it takes less time?

Comment: Yes - allocating, writing, and freeing all that data takes extra time.

Comment: Actually, I'm not so sure about that, @TimNyborg. On an ipython terminal on my machine, running `%timeit sum(1 for i in range(9999999) if i%2==0)`  gives `922 ms ± 3.71 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)` as result, while running `%timeit len(['' for i in range(9999999) if i%2==0])` results in `814 ms ± 7.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`. However, I'm no so sure what's the underlying reason.

Comment: So, can I use the 2 interchangably?